# Qualcomm Diag frame Time synchronization in Quectel EC25

Tags: time, synchronization, qualcomm, quectel

I have an EC25 device. As you know, Diag data can be extracted from one of the device serial port. A Diag frame looks like this:

```
10003400340076136003505C3898F9000900000000000000010001010000000000000000000000000C000000060000000BEF280000000000
```

We know that

```
6003505C3898F900
```

represents time with a precision of 1.25 microseconds.
My question is, how does the Qualcomm processor obtain this time? Does it come from GPS? If there is no GPS, does that mean this time is not accurate? Or is this time somehow obtained from the mobile network? For me, this time is about two minutes different from NTP. What is the reason for this difference?